# C Programming help - providing user with option to exit a program

Tags: c

I've written a program to compute the running sum of any numbers input by a user. I need to provide the user with an option to exit the program at any stage, which I'm not sure how to do.  I was looking into it and think getchar() is what I need to use but I'm not sure, there seem to be a few ways to do it.

I basically want the user to be able to hit "e" on the keyboard if they want to exit the program, and it will terminate.  The comments in the code are just ideas I had so I've left them there. Help appreciated, thanks.  Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     float number;
     float sum = 0;
     int i = 1;

     //char exit [2] = {'e'};
     //void exit (int status);

     printf ("Please enter number or enter \"e\" to exit at any stage:\n");
     scanf ("%f", &number);

       // if user inputs string e, program will terminate
       /* if (number == 'e')
          {
          printf ("Exiting the program...\n");
          exit(0);
          }                                       */

     while (i == 1)
     {
        sum += number;
        printf ("Sum: %.2f\n", sum);
        printf ("Please enter number:\n");
        scanf ("%f", &number);

        // if user inputs string e, program will terminate
        /*    if (number == 'e')
              {
                 printf ("Exiting the program...\n");
                 exit(0);
              }                                         */
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the while(i=1) before the first printf which is after int i = 1;

Comment: If you want your user to be able to type only "e" and not "e" followed by the return key I don't think there is a portable way to do it. You'll have to use platform specific functions.

Comment: What's wrong with good ole Ctrl+c?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
scanf ("%f", &number);
```

to

```
if(1!=scanf ("%f", &number)){
    if (getchar() == 'e'){
        printf ("Exiting the program...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, that's quite cleverer than my answers :)

Comment: Should also be some code to handle when they enter other letters otherwise the program will behave strangely

Comment: @MattMcNabb ; sure, but He does not believe that the errors handling at present. I think it's close to the answer of his want.

Comment: I do not want to afterthought excessive before it is desired.