# C Programming help - Option for user to exit program

Tags: c

this is a follow on question from one I asked recently:

[C Programming help - providing user with option to exit a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391308/c-programming-help-providing-user-with-option-to-exit-a-program)

I now have a new problem.  I can get the program to exit if a user enters any letter which is great, but now if a number is entered nothing happens. The while loop doesn't seem to run..

Can you please have a look at my code and see if you can spot what's wrong, thanks.  Also, ideally i'd like xterm's window to close if the user wishes to exit. I'd be greatful if anyone could show me how to do this.  Anyway here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     float number;
     float sum = 0;


     printf ("Please enter number or enter any letter to exit:\n");
     scanf ("%f", &number);

     // if user ENTERS a letter, program will terminate

     if(1!=scanf ("%f", &number))
     {
        getchar();
        printf ("Exiting the program...\n");
        exit(0);
     }


     while (1)
     {
        sum += number;
        printf ("Sum: %.2f\n", sum);
        printf ("Please enter number or enter any letter to exit:\n");
        scanf ("%f", &number);

        // if user ENTERS a letter, program will terminate

             if(1!=scanf ("%f", &number))
             {
                getchar();
                printf ("Exiting the program...\n");
                exit(0);
             }

     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `Exiting...` code path executes two `scanf()`s and one `getchar()`.  This seems like an element of the problem.  Can you state clearly what sequence of events should happen in order for the user to cause the program to exit?

Comment: Yeah sure, the program computes the running sum of any numbers input by the user. If the user enters any letter on the keyboard instead of a number, the program should exit (and ideally the shell window should close)

Comment: Ok.  FYI, your instructor may be trying to include the [`do ... while ()` loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop#C) construct as a portion of this assignment.

Comment: I'm going to change it to a do while loop but I'd still have the same problem, right?

Comment: Indeed.  First fix the items I describe in my comment (it can't be intentional to hit those three functions in that case, correct?).  Then consider the answers provided.  Then you could consider simplifying things with a do-while.

Comment: @Brain Cain Will do/try : ] Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As @BrianCain commented: you are calling `scanf` a second time in your `if` statement.  If you entered a letter for the first `scanf`, it forces the second to immediately fail; if you entered a number for the first, then the second is waiting for you to enter another number.

Answer (score 0):

I removed two of your scanf functions and it seems to fix the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float number;
    float sum = 0;


    printf ("Please enter number or enter any letter to exit:\n");


    // if user ENTERS a letter, program will terminate

    if(1!=scanf ("%f", &number))
    {
        getchar();
        printf ("Exiting the program...\n");
        exit(0);
    }


     while (1)
     {
        sum += number;
        printf ("Sum: %.2f\n", sum);
        printf ("Please enter number or enter any letter to exit:\n");


        // if user ENTERS a letter, program will terminate

        if(1!=scanf ("%f", &number))
        {
            getchar();
            printf ("Exiting the program...\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The scanf in your if erased the value of the previous one you did.

Answer (score 0):

While the previous two answers are essentially correct, the simple (and clear) version would be:

```
if(number == 1)
    break;
```

Place this right after your original `scanf()` and get rid of the other `if(..) ..;` condition entirely. This will test to see if the number '1' was entered, and if so will break the infinite loop, allowing the program to continue down to the `return 0;` statement.

It will also deal with what could be confusing style, which is having an exit condition (the final `return 0;`) that's essentially impossible to get to, or should be.